# PrestaShop Fatal error in function isLogged()

Tags: php, html, mysql, cookies, prestashop

Well, im developing a CMS based form with a copy-center-system ([this is the form](http://www.papelariaveloso.com/content/8-C%C3%B3pias)), but i need the $cookie->id_customer.
But i get an error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function isLogged() on a non-object in /home/papelari/public_html/modules/mymodule/submit.php on line 13

```
<?php 
/*
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","papelari","509494218");
 if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

 mysql_select_db("papelari_Veloso", $con); */

 global $cookie;

if(!$cookie->isLogged())
{
 echo 'Please login';
 exit;
}
else
{
 echo 'Hi, ' . $cookie->customer_firstname. ' ' .$cookie->customer_lastname . '<br/>';
 echo 'We contact to you: '. $cookie->email;
}

/* $sql="INSERT INTO ps_copias (id_customer, file, cor, copias, pags, papel, gramagem,       flag) VALUES('$cookie-            >id_customer','$_POST[file]','$_POST[cor]','$_POST[copias]','$_POST[pags]','$_POST[papel]','$_POST[gramagem]', 0)";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Enviado com sucesso!"; 

mysql_close($con); */
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `$cookie` is not defined. Paste this at the beginning of your script :

```
<?php
include("../config/config.inc.php");
$cookie = new Cookie("ps");

if ($cookie->isLogged()) {
    // your code
}
```

You may have to adapt `config.inc.php` include path depending on your own script

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the `global $cookie` is for.

Make sure that `$cookie` is defined by using `var_dump($cookie);` to make sure the variable is what you think it is (and contains the correct functions).

Answer (score 0):

For prestashop 1.5, to check is user is logged or not :

```
Context::getContext()>customer>isLogged()
```